# Type 'Avatar' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | ComponentType<any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have following JSX.

```
<StyledCardContainer>
  <StyledAvatar<Avatar> bg={getRandomBGColor()}>{data.alpha_2}</StyledAvatar>
    <h4>{data.name}</h4>
    <StyledCount>{data.count}</StyledCount>
  </StyledCardContainer>
```

`StyledAvatar` is a styled component component which is following.

```
export const StyledAvatar = styled.div`
  width: 90px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: ${(props: any) => props.bg};
`;
```

It returns below error.

```
Type 'Avatar' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | ComponentType<any>'.
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I solve this?

Comment: Missing closing bracket after StyledAvatar i.e. "<StyledAvatar" instead of "<StyledAvatar>" ?

Comment: You can fix the error by replacing `StyledAvatar<Avatar>` with `StyledAvatar<typeof Avatar>`, but are you sure you want to pass it as a type parameter? Using ``const StyledAvatar = styled(Avatar)` ..`` seems to make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The way i solved it is by passing type when i declare component.
In your example It would be:

```
  <StyledAvatar bg={getRandomBGColor()}>{data.alpha_2}</StyledAvatar>
```

and declaration

```
export const StyledAvatar = styled.div<Avatar>`
```

Hope it helps if you still dont have consistent way!